# Где находится функция peekb()?

Tags: c++, c

Где находится функция `peekb()`?

В заголовочном файле `dos.h` ее нету.

В данном случае нужна для чтения данных из bios. Может, есть какие-то аналоги?

Comment: кажется тут ftp://ftp.cmpe.emu.edu.tr/Borland/BC3/CRTL/CLIB/PEEK.C

Comment: Боюсь, что в современных виндах она не применима, она была для 16-разрядного, реального режима процессора. Хотя есть слухи, что в XP она еще могла что то прочитать